# How to show data in offline mode (that has been fetched from firebase) in android?

Tags: android, firebase, offline

I have made an app that shows data in the app which has been fetched from firebase and when in offline mode means in the absence of internet connection, it does not show any data and keeps waiting for the connection to be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the response from server in **local database**, so whenever user opened your app without internet connection you can show data from local database.

[How to use sqlite database in android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

[How to check if user is connected to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239019/5264543)

Comment: Thanks a lot! but can we do this with SharedPreferences ?

Comment: Yes you can achieve this with SharedPreferences too but it's not easy and i don't recommend you to do it with SharedPreferences.